# SQL Query to Group/SUM Columns C, D, when A, B are equal

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL Table that has 4 columns, we will call them C1, C2, C3, and C4.

In this data, I have a data set like so:

```
C1,C2,C3,C4
A,B,12,24
C,D,23,13
A,D,19,15
B,C,15,15
A,C,21,9
B,D,19,2
B,A,8,19
D,C,29,1
```

I need to get an output like follows:

```
A,71
B,66
D,59
C,48
```

I attempted to write a query, but just can't seem to wrap my head around how to Sum two fields when two other fields are equal and group/sort them.

```
SELECT C1, SUM(C3,C4) AS Total
WHERE C1 = C2
GROUP BY C1
ORDER BY C1 Desc;
```

This returns a null set and I know why, becase C1 and C2 are not equal in the same row, but can't seem to figure out what to do next.

Comment: `A,71` how do you get to 71, its 12+24?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the declaration that the sums come from where C1 gets its value from C3, and C2 gets it's Value from C4.

So for the instance above, A = 12+19+21+19 for a total of 71.

Comment: Sounds like you should normalize your data instead. Have two columns, more rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this as:

```
select col, sum(val)
from ((select c1 as col, c3 as val from t
      ) union all
      (select c2, c4 from t
      )
     ) cc
group by col;
```

This seems like the simplest approach given the data you have provided.  This should have much better performance than an approach that uses `or` in a `join` condition.

Comment: I tried this as well and it is much simpler and works perfectly.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

**1st solution (MySql 8.0):**

```
WITH d AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT C1 AS name FROM tablename
  UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT C2 AS name FROM tablename
)

SELECT tt.name, SUM(tt.value) AS total FROM (
  SELECT 
    d.name,
    CASE WHEN t.C1 = d.name THEN C3 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN t.C2 = d.name THEN C4 ELSE 0 END AS value
  FROM d
  INNER JOIN tablename AS t 
  ON t.C1 = d.name OR t.C2 = d.name 
) AS tt
GROUP BY name;
```

See [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kTE7UPoqnrR1Xcs5ohV8sT/0)

**2nd solution (MySql 5.7):**

```
SELECT tt.name, SUM(tt.value) AS total FROM (
SELECT 
  d.name,
  CASE WHEN t.C1 = d.name THEN C3 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN t.C2 = d.name THEN C4 ELSE 0 END AS value
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT C1 AS name FROM tablename
  UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT C2 AS name FROM tablename
) AS  d
INNER JOIN tablename AS t 
ON t.C1 = d.name OR t.C2 = d.name 
) AS tt
GROUP BY name;
```

See [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nPJ2M4Ja46bqPbWAsfwdgx/0)

Comment: What I shared is a very limited set of a table with thousands of rows.  How would I scale this to look for unique values first in C1 without writing a new manual line entry for each of the unique values?  The unique values found in C1 will at some point be in C2 as well.

To give some more background information, this table tracks the points that players earn in a sports league, both at home location, and away.  I need to generate a sum of total points per player and get the values for both home and away.

Comment: See the 2nd solution

Comment: Solution 2 works great on MySQL 8, but I am running 5.7 on my webserver and it throws an error.

Query Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'd AS ( SELECT DISTINCT C1 AS name FROM tablename UNION SELECT DISTINCT C2 ' at line 1

Comment: See the 3d solution.

Comment: Perfect.  That worked great.  Thank you so much for the help. :)